# HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Getting the following error on Python AppEngine:

> HTTPException: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/115429583296661000087/bookshelves/1001/volumes?maxResults=12&startIndex=0

URL is .json format, and im grabbing it via the following code on my application:

```
request = urllib2.Request(bookShelfUrl, None, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
bookShelfJsonRaw = urllib2.urlopen(request)  
bookShelfJsonObject = json.load(bookShelfJsonRaw)
```

works fine when testing in localhost, only gives an error in production. it also worked fine in production up until today when it mysteriously started returning that error.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Books gData API was timing out because I wasn't passing in the country code. For whatever reason it worked fine without the country on a local test server but whenever I pushed it to production it would timeout. After adding country=US the json feed worked fine.

```
bookShelfUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/users/' + \
bookShelfId + \
'/bookshelves/1001/volumes?' + \
'maxResults=' + str(maxResults) + \
'&startIndex=' + str(startIndex) + \
'&country=US'
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not know was the issue solved by google or it start working right after i modify the code and specify timout parameter instead of deafults for http instantiation:

```
httplib2.Http(timeout=15)
```